# How to redefine \ref as \eqref?

Tags: macros

I would like to redefine `\ref` as `\eqref`, but `\renewcommand{\ref}{\eqref}` doesn't work. I would guess this is hapenning because `\eqref` is internally defined as `\newcommand{\eqref}{(\ref)}`, but I'm not sure about it. Any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, in `amsmath.sty`, `\eqref` is defined as

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
```

so you could say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\origref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\origref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{a}
Section~\ref{a}? Equation~\ref{b}
\begin{equation}\label{b}
a=b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the inconsistencies that the redefinition introduces; you are cross-referencing section `(1)`, but your document has section `1`; a similar problem will appear for floats, and other objects in your document.

#### Adendum

Perhaps, if you are interested in redefining the cross-reference format for a particular type of object, the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package could be a better option; a little example in which I changed the formatting for cross-referencing figures, leaving all other cross.references unalatered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{figure}{figure~(#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{figure}{Figure~(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{a}
Section~\ref{a}. Equation~\ref{b}. \Cref{c}? or \cref{c}?
\begin{equation}\label{b}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{test figure}
\label{c}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I take your point. I wanted to prevent from having references to equations in both forms  `(1) ` and  `1 `. I think it's better to use  `\eqref ` for references now.

Answer (score 8):

The macro `\p@equation` can be used to change the equation references of `\ref`.
Usually `\p@<counter>` is used to add a prefix to the reference of counter `<counter>` and does not take an argument. But with an additional `\expandafter`, the counter value can be catched as simple argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@equation}{%
  \expandafter\@p@equation
}
\newcommand*{\@p@equation}[1]{%
  \textup{\tagform@{#1}}% see definition of `\eqref`
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}\label{sec:hello}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:einstein}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
References: Section \ref{sec:hello} and equation \ref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Drawback: The reference `\ref` should not be used inside `\tag`, otherwise the result is duplicated parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

You can selectively define the format of `\ref` using the `fncylab` package, which is equivalent to (but more packaged than) Heiko's answer.  For example:

```
\usepackage{fncylab}
\labelformat{equation}{(#1)}
\section{A section}\label{s:section}
\[ \label{eq:eqn} ... \]
\ref{s:section}\ref{eq:eqn}
```

will print the equation number in parentheses but the section number normally.  I have a standing preamble to define `\labelformat{section}{Section~#1}` and so on.